# Force Simplify to group certain variables in a polynomial

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to regroup terms in a polynomial such as

```
3 c x + a (x + 2 y + z) + b (y + 2 z)
```

in the following way:

```
x (a + 3 c) + y (2 a + b) + z (a + 2 b) .
```

However `// Expand // Simplify` returns the expression unchanged.

Is it possible to force `Simplify` to group selected variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collect[3 c x + a (x + 2 y + z) + b (y + 2 z), {x, y, z}]
```

(*

(a + 3 c) x + (2 a + b) y + (a + 2 b) z

*)